# Facebook OAuth login not getting the user profile in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm fighting with the identity parts of ASP.NET Core 2.2 again. This time its Facebook login. Google and Microsoft work with some small tweaks but Facebook has me stumped.

Here's my config.

```
        "Facebook": {
            "ClientId": "See secrets.json",
            "ClientSecret": "See secrets.json",
            "AuthorizationEndpoint": "https://www.facebook.com/v5.0/dialog/oauth",
            "TokenEndpoint": "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token",
            "UserInformationEndpoint": "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,first_name,email",
            "CallbackPath": "/oauth2/facebook",
            "Scope": [ "public_profile", "email" ]
        }
```

Using Fiddler I cannot see any attempt to call the `/me` resource to get the profile. I *can* see the backchannel call out to get the access token and I see the response looks like good JSON to me and the token works; I can call the Facebook Graph API manually and get my profile.

I had Fiddler trace a working Google login and I see a token come back with what appears to be the same JSON schema as Facebook uses, and then another clear request/response on the backchannel to get my Google profile.

Facebook returns `{ "access_token", "token_type", "expires_in" }` while
Google return `{ "access_token", "expires_in", "scope", "token_type", "id_token" }`.

Sadly, because I'm using the Microsoft framework and didn't roll my own OAuth code this time, I am unable to see what's happening internally and I think Microsoft chose not to log anything for fear of leaking secrets into logs.

I'm out of ideas.

---

Exact same issue after setting up LinkedIn. Token comes back looking fine but it doesn't even try to call to get the profile.

What a severely costly nightmare the Identity framework is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the Facebook login working. I was looking at why the Microsoft and Google ones work and saw that they use their own extension methods, like `AddGoogle` and not the vanilla `AddOAuth`.

Looking at the code on GitHub reveals that each of the named ones uses a custom handler.

This tells me that each OAuth provider is incapable of following a standard and so custom code is needed for each one! Lovely job everyone. Top marks.

I'll try using the Google (etc) handlers for LinkedIn and see if any are "compatible".